# How do I check if my Facebook account is accessed from another computer at the same time?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I would like to know if it is possible to check if my Facebook account is logged in at the same time from two different computers?

Answer (score 4):

From your [Facebook security settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security), there's an option to [view active sessions](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions&view) which will tell you the location & the device from where your Facebook accounts are logged into.

[image]